# unable to save a .py file in sublime using django

Tags: django, python-2.7, sublimetext3

I am a total noob in python.I am trying to save a .py file which I wrote it using the sublime3 editor but it doesn't allow me to save it.It says the file is read only.I am using django framework .Any suggestions ?

Comment: your question has nothing to do with django/python and can only be an OS-related permissions problem based on the setup of files ans users on your system. I think there is a more appropriate board for that, but either way more details would be necessary to provide an answer.

Comment: I got reason for why this problem occurred .I was starting sublime from the terminal and it didn't had the admin privilege so the file was locked,my bad .So, now I start sublime with admin privillage and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

please check if you are permitted to write on that directory.